# Change borderColor after choosing an answer to normal in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm having a quiz screen. When I click on any answer in the first question, the borderColor of the selected answer will become blue. But when I move to the 2nd question, it is still blue at a random position. I try to make it become normal like this but it is not working.

[image].

Any solutions?

**This is my code**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const {width: WIDTH} = Dimensions.get('window');
export default class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      answer: null,
      changeborder: 0,
      selected: -1,
    };
  }
  _onPress(val, index) {
    this.setState({changeborder: val, selected: index});
  }

  renderOptions = (question) => {
    const {changeborder} = this.state;
    const {selected} = this.state;
    const result = [];
    question.WrongAnswer.forEach((item, index) => {
      let key = `${question.id}-${index}`;
      if (index === this.props.correctPosition) {
        let key2 = `${question.id}-100`;
        result.push(
          <TouchableOpacity // Correct answer
            onPress={() => this._onPress(1)}
            style={[
              styles.inputContainer,
              {borderColor: changeborder == 1 ? '#59B7c9' : 'black'},
            ]}
            value={question.RightAnswer}
            key={key2}>
            <Text style={styles.inputText}>{question.RightAnswer}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>,
        );
      }
      result.push(
        <TouchableOpacity // 3 Incorrect answer
          onPress={() => this._onPress(2, index)}
          style={[
            styles.inputContainer,
            {
              borderColor:
                index == selected && changeborder == 2 ? '#59B7c9' : 'black',
            },
          ]}
          value={item}
          key={key}>
          <Text style={styles.inputText}>{item}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
      );
    });

    return result;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View style={{padding: 12}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'left'}}>
              Câu {this.props.current+1} :
            </Text>
            <Text style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              {this.props.question.Titles}:
            </Text>
            <Text style={{paddingTop: 10, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
              {this.props.question.Question}
            </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
            <View style={{paddingLeft: 20}}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onSelect={(index, answer) => this.setState({answer})}
                selectedIndex={null}>
                {this.renderOptions(this.props.question)}
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            <View style={{marginLeft: 40, marginTop: 20}}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonSignup}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.onSelect(this.state.answer);
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}
                > Next question </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you initializing 'selected' while creating state?
 `this.state = { answer: 0, selected: -1};`

Comment: I just initialized it but it's still not working. Sorry for late reply

Comment: How about just initializing it back to defaults when the user presses on Next Question button? `onPress={() => { this.props.onSelect(this.state.answer); this.setState({answer:0 , selected: -1}); }}>`

Comment: your solution is not working. But I use onPress = {() => {this.setState ({answer: 0, selected: -1}); }}> is fine. The current problem is that when choosing the correct answer, the correct anwser of the next question will be blue. If I choose wrong answer, my problem will be fixed

Comment: hmm.. not sure if this could help. try sending index even for correct answer:
`onPress={() => this._onPress(1, index)` and modify your borderColor (for correct answer) as `{borderColor: index == selected && changeborder == 1 ? '#59B7c9' : 'black'},`

Comment: i know what is `this.state { answer : 0}` and `this.setState {anwer:0}` mean. But what is `this.state.answer` means? I dont' understand it

Comment: I didn't get your question. But anyways, I see that you have introduced a new state variable i.e. changeborder and using it to determine the color for border. Earlier I had seen that you were using variable 'answer' instead.

Comment: Since there have been some code changes, I'll just give you some hints and you could see if it helps. 1)  Try setting the state to default values when user clicks on next question. 2) set state to default in ComponentDidMount. 3) update changeBorder state variable when you call _onPress().